# Object #<Element> has no method when trying to clear map (Google Maps API V3)

Tags: jquery, google-maps, typeerror

I'm working on a project that uses Google Maps API V3 and JQuery. Basically, the program calls items from a database depending on a time that the user selects and then displays these items on the map as markers.

It is working fine up until this point. I want to clear the markers when the user changes the time so that irrelevant markers aren't left on the map.

However, when I attach the `clearLocations()` function to any of the JQuery time selection elements it throws up the error:

> Object # has no method 'setMap'`.

Here is the JavaScript for Google Maps that is throwing the error when called:

```
function clearLocations() {
if (markers) {
    for (i in markers) {
    markers[i].setMap(null);
    }
    markers.length = 0;
    }
}
```

Here is the JQuery function calling it when a slider is moved:

```
function slideTime(event, ui){
            var val0 = $("#time-slider").slider("values", 0),
                val1 = $("#time-slider").slider("values", 1),
                chosenDate = Math.round(Date.parse($('#datepicker').datetimepicker('getDate')) / 1000),
                minrange = chosenDate + (val0 * 60),
                maxrange = chosenDate + (val1 * 60),
                timedifference = (maxrange - minrange)/60,
                fulldate = new Date(minrange * 1000),
                enddate = new Date(maxrange * 1000),
                fdate = fulldate.getDate(),
                fmonth = fulldate.getMonth()+1,
                fyear = fulldate.getFullYear(),
                edate = enddate.getDate(),
                emonth = enddate.getMonth()+1,
                eyear = enddate.getFullYear(),
                fhours = fulldate.getHours(),
                fminutes = fulldate.getMinutes(),
                ehours = enddate.getHours(),
                eminutes = enddate.getMinutes();
                if (fmonth < 10) {
                fmonth = "0" + fmonth; }
                if (fdate < 10) {
                fdate = "0" + fdate; }
                if (fhours < 10) {
                fhours = "0" + fhours; }
                if (fminutes < 10) {
                fminutes = "0" + fminutes; }
                if (emonth < 10) {
                emonth = "0" + emonth; }
                if (edate < 10) {
                edate = "0" + edate; }
                if (ehours < 10) {
                ehours = "0" + ehours; }
                if (eminutes < 10) {
                eminutes = "0" + eminutes; }


            $("#final-from-value").text(fdate + '/' + fmonth + '/' + fyear + ' ' + fhours + ':' + fminutes);
            $("#final-to-value").text(edate + '/' + emonth + '/' + eyear + ' ' + ehours + ':' + eminutes);
            $("#hidden-start").val(minrange);
            $("#hidden-finish").val(maxrange);

            clearLocations();
            searchMap();
        }
```

I also have a datetimepicker that calls the function on change as well:

```
<input id="datepicker" name="date" type="text" onchange="slideTime(); searchMap(); clearLocations()" />
```

I've tried everything I can think of but I honestly have no idea what's doing it. Thanks for any help. And let me know if there is anything else you need to see.

**UPDATE**
If I don't call the searchMap() function there are no errors, but if searchMap() is called after clearing the locations it doesn't like it.

Here is the code for searchMap()

```
function searchMap() {
    //clearLocations();
    var getstart = $("#hidden-start").val();
    var getfinish = $("#hidden-finish").val();
  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
  downloadUrl("php/xml.php?start=" + getstart + "&finish=" + getfinish, function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("title");
      var address = markers[i].getAttribute("url");
      var priority = parseInt(markers[i].getAttribute("priority"));
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
      //var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        zIndex: priority,
        icon: iconType[priority],
      });
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Is `markers` a global variable ?

Comment: I think it is something to do with the way the markers are created. But I can't figure it out! This is killing me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't what is in your `markers` variables, but try this :

```
for (i in markers) {
    if(!markers.hasOwnProperty(i)){continue;}
    markers[i].setMap(null);
}
```

Comment: Same as Andreas' answer. Didn't work, I think the function itself works but not when called by one of the JQuery elements?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `markers` is an array.
So use this for iterating the markers

```
function clearLocations() {
    if (markers && markers.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
             markers[i].setMap(null);
        }

        markers = [];
    }
}
```

`for (var i in ...)` is for **objects only**

Comment: Didn't work, I think the function itself works but not when called by one of the JQuery elements?

Answer (score 0):

Your `markers` array doesn't contain objects of type `google.maps.Marker` it contains XML element objects because of this `markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");`